# cannot connect to remote sql express server 2012 from ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sql-server, openssl, freetds, ubuntu-22.04

I recently installed ubuntu 22.04
I then installed openssl, unixodbc-dev, freetds, and mssqlodbc18 using apt
When I try to connect to a remote SQL Server I get anerror. It is SQL Server Express 2012.

> Error 20002 (severity 9):
> Adaptive Server connection failed

I changed the FreeTds.conf file to include as below

```
[sqlserver]
        host = XXX.XXX.XXX.X
        port = 1433
        tds version = 7.4
        instance=XX_XXXX
```

I also reduced the CipherString to `SECLEVEL=0` in the openssl.cnf file. however, when I try to connect it gives me the same error.

If I telnet to the server on that port I can connect.

The same problem persists when I use pyodbc from python to connect and execute a query on the SQL Server instance.

Comment: If you know it's listening on port 1433 (i.e.: sounds like it's the default `MSSQLSERVER` instance, not SQL Express) then try removing the `instance` property from the `freetds.conf` file. When you specify an instance name the client is meant to send an SSRQ (SQL Server Resolution Query) to the SQL Browser service listening on udp/1434 at the target server, which then returns the TCP port number that the instance is listening on. If there are multiple instances installed on the target server it may be attempting to connect to a different one than you're expecting.

Comment: Likewise, if you are intending to connect to the `SQLEXPRESS` instance on the target server then remove the port number from the `freetds.conf` file and ensure that the SQL Express instance has its TCP/IP server protocol enabled and is prepared to accept connections from beyond localhost [127.0.0.1]. If you change any configuration here make sure to restart the SQL Browser service so that it loads the new settings.